# xsd pattern not working with more than two regex separated by OR ( | )

Tags: regex, xsd

I am facing some problem with following xsd pattern ...

```
 <xsd:pattern value="\d+(,\d+)*(,[*])|\d+(,\d+)*|\d+(,[*])(,\d+)+" />
```

In the above pattern I want to allow user to enter following patterns only:

```
1,2,3
1,*,3
1,2,*
```

But when I try to enter 1,2,* it gives me following exception ...

```
Unknown Exception occurred while Updating = For input string: "*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with the expression but it can be improved and doing so might prevent the error. The fault might also be in the way the results of the regular expression are used, not with the regular expression itself.

The regular expression given in the question is `\d+(,\d+)*(,[*])|\d+(,\d+)*|\d+(,[*])(,\d+)+`.

Testing it in Notepad++ v6.5.5 shows it matches all three example lines, however the expression is not anchored to the start and end of the line. Just adding one `^` and one `$` is not sufficient because of the precedence of the `|`.

Using this expressions matches all the lines:

```
^(\d+(,\d+)*(,[*])|\d+(,\d+)*|\d+(,[*])(,\d+)+)$
```

Could also use `^\d+(,\d+)*(,[*])$|^\d+(,\d+)*$|^\d+(,[*])(,\d+)+$` but this seems harder to read and understand.

Within the regular expression

- The `[*]` matches one character and might be better written as `\*`.
- The `(,[*])` matches and captures the two character sequence `,*`. There is no point in capturing this as it is fixed in all places. So this can be replaced with `,\*` throughout.
- Each alternative start with `\d+`, this could be factored out.
- The first two alternatives only differ with the final `(,[*]) clause.

Making these changes gives the expression:

```
^\d+((,\d+)*(,\*)*|,\*(,\d+)+)$
```

The question shows only patterns with two commas but the regular expression matches lines with multiple commas however it only allows the second or the final value to be replaced with `*`. So the original expression actually matches

```
1,2,3
1,*,3
1,2,*
1,2,3,4,5
1,*,3,4,5
1,2,3,*,*
1,2,3,4,*
```

but does not match

```
1,*,*,4,5
1,*,3,*,5
1,*,3,4,*
1,2,*,*,5
1,2,*,4,*
1,2,*,4,5
1,2,3,*,5
```

To match the given inputs with only two commas I would use:

```
^\d+,(\d+,\d+|\d+,\*|\*,\d+)$
```

To match a string with many numbers separated by commas but only one (but not the first one) replaced by a `*` I would use:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*(,\*)?(,\d+)*$
```

Note the `?` in the line above. It means match zero or one occurrence of the preceding item. So it allows a `,*` to occur once in the string.

Comment: Adrian thanks for your response. after using following expression...        ^\d+(,\d+)*(,\*)?(,\d+)*$  i am getting following exception, but it is working fine in http://regex101.com/. Exception are :                         cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1,2,3' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^\d+(,\d+)*(,\*)?(,\d+)*$' for type 'OfferType'.
Column is 41 at line number 23
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '1,2,3' of element 'OfferId' is not valid.
Column is 41 at line number 23

Comment: @ashutosh I think the fault has nothing to do with the regular expression. I think it relates to how the data is processed after being matched by the regular expression.